# Is it possible to have multi project SBT with version.sbt for each subproject

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-release

I have a multi project SBT with four subprojects. I'd like to have separate versions for each subproject with a version.sbt in each. I'm using [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release). Readme says there is a setting ***release-version-file*** that should do this but it doesn't seem to be working for me. This is the error I get

```
release-version-file := file("subproject/version.sbt")
```

> /source/root/subproject/build.sbt:3: error: not found: value release
>
> release-version-file := file("subproject/version.sbt")

I also found another setting ***releaseVersionFile*** this one did't throw any error but it also didn't seem to pick up the version from correct file.

```
releaseVersionFile := file("subproject/version.sbt")
```

I'm using sbt 0.13.15, sbt-release 1.0.5 and sbt-assembly 0.14.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve indepedent multi module versioning with sbt-release plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746376/how-to-achieve-indepedent-multi-module-versioning-with-sbt-release-plugin)

Comment: Are you sure? The 'versionFile' setting mentioned in the answer no longer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did get this to work with `releaseVersionFile`. More info in this github [issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release/issues/175).